# Bind ng-pattern value from JSON

Tags: regex, json, angularjs

I have JSON configuration that is being parsed and creates the form.

```
"fields":[
            {
               "field_template" : "first_name",
               "display_name" : "First name",
               "pattern" : ""
            },
            {
               "field_template" : "date_of_birth",
               "display_name" : "Date of birth",
               "pattern" : ""
            },
...
]
```

I read the json with this code:

```
$http.get('fields.json').success(function(result) {
              $scope.fields = result.fields;
 });
```

Render fields in the view:

```
<div class="control-group" ng-repeat="f in fields">
            <label class="control-label" for="input">{{f['display_name']}}</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="text" id="input" name="{{f['field_template']}}" ng-pattern="f['pattern']" ng-model="f['field_template']" class="input-xlarge">
            </div>
          </div>
```

What I need is universal regex that match any string for first name and regex for date that can be read form json.

If I leave "pattern" : "" balnk, it reports:
Error: Expected f.pattern to be a RegExp but was Pa/e

See here http://jsfiddle.net/894bb/6/

If I put regex:

```
^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$
```

everywhere just for sake of example it reports:

```
Error: JSON.parse: bad escaped character
```

See here http://jsfiddle.net/894bb/7/

How to put regex that match all strings, on fields like first name and how to modify regex for date that does not report error, when read from json?

Comment: please provide some Plunker/Fiddle to help us to help you

Comment: @MaximShoustin Fiddle added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try to create a javascript RegExp for each field by looping on your value when loaded

I made a little fiddle here :http://jsfiddle.net/DotDotDot/g5tY7/
After the get(), I just looped on each value then did :

```
        for(var i in $scope.fields){
            $scope.fields[i].pattern=new RegExp($scope.fields[i].pattern);
        }
```

This creates a JS RegExp using the text in the JSON, which avoid any error

Hope this helps

++

Little edit : if you want the pattern to work correctly, don't forget to escape all the "\" in it, your date pattern should be :

```
^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\\d\\d$
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to put regex that match all strings *[1]*, on fields like first name and how to modify regex for date that does not report error, when read from json *[2]*?

#### [1]

A regex that matches all strings is `.*`.

#### [2]

The problem is the single `\`. Replace that with double `\\`.

Comment: It reports the same errors. Can you please try it in my jsFiddle example.